# Where does Firebase fit in?

Tags: php, database, html, firebase-realtime-database

This is a conceptual and rather basic question. So I know HTML, CSS, JS and now AngularJS.

And I was wondering how I could build functional web apps without knowledge of server side programming languages - and chanced upon Firebase.

Could someone please explain to me how I could use Firebase to build web apps -  with my limited knowledge in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a full-featured web application without any server-side logic and input validation does not make much sense.

If you are unwilling to learn a server-side language and a proper framework, take a look at NodeJS. It allows you to write server-side code in JavaScript, so if you catch up on security principles you should do OK.

Good luck!